# 3 computers - 3 networks - 1 IP ADRESS possible?

Tags: ip

So here's the thing. There is a certain website that me and a few other friends would like to use with the same account. The problem is that this website allows only one user to use it. So that means that if we would be logging in from different computers and networks they would ban us because they would see many different IPs.

The question is how could we resolve that problem, so that it would look like we are signing in with only one IP.

Could VLN do the trick or what service should i search for?

Many thanks on your help!

Comment: You need to come up with the cash and pay for two more users. The problem is not that the three of you can't use the same user, the problem is that your are trying to steal from the business.

Comment: Sorry, we're not here to help you to steal.

Comment: Have 1 PC running and access this PC via Remote Admin tools?

Comment: Put all the computers in one house behind a nat firewall.

Answer (score 1):

In order to appear to come from the same IP Address, there are some possibilities:

- A VPN service will generally make you appear to come from the same IP address as each other, but that all depends very much on whether or not the VPN shares a public IP address.  Many VPN services do.
- Using a proxy server or Socks server can allow you to appear to come from a single IP address.

Using either of the above methods *CAN BE DETECTED*, due to the fact that each of your computers will have its own fingerprint (Browser & OS Information) when visiting a website.  Usage of these methods is also not guaranteed, as the service you are using may use a pool of IP's, so your IP address may appear to change day after day.

**Please do not use this answer to defraud a legitimate business.  This answer is only provided for educational purposes, and to assist people who have a valid need.  As the OP's intentions are not clear, I am giving him or her the benefit of the doubt**